# Instagram custom in app browser for Ionic

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am new to ionic 1 and I want to do something like Instagram in-app browser. Please see screenshot here:
[image: IG In-App Browser]

Do you know any existing library that I can use in my project? I would gladly appreciate any kind of help. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use [Cordova In App Browser plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser) for Ionic 1 project. 
If you are using ngCordova, you can use [ngCordova InAppBrowser](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/inAppBrowser/)

Here's a link to Ionic Native In app browser wrapper if you are using Ionic 2. [In App Browser Ionic Native](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/in-app-browser/)

Comment: Thanks but I already use this library. Have you seen the in app browser of Instagram and facebook?

Comment: Yes. Would you explain in what ways are they different or what is it that you want different?

Comment: You may notice that its in app browser can be pulled up and pulled down. I want something like that and if ever I want the browser be on top of my fixed footer.

Comment: I just triggered the in app browser in both android and ios, and I was only able to pull down/up the in app browser in iOS. It's a platform specific feature, seems like.

Comment: Can you show me a demo video of it? Keen to see it thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure how to make a demo video. Why don't you get a hold of both ios and android devices? Open up facebook. Open an advertisement and observe behavior of the inapp browser for both platforms

Comment: Hello Anjil no worries I found it myself